# Where is Ciri's loot?

Tags: the-witcher-3

When I play as Ciri, I can loot various things: herbs, chests, and more. For example:

[image]

However, Ciri doesn't have inventory of her own, and I wasn't able to find the things she loot in Geralt's inventory.

Where is the loot? Or is it just lost?

Answer (score 12):

Any loot picked up while playing as Ciri is not transferred to Geralt and is otherwise unobtainable.

Comment: So any idea why it's possible? Just a tease, or a bug?

Comment: In the specific case of the first time you play as Ciri in Velen, you need to pick up the herbs to create the potion that'll do extra damage to the Wolf King. I honestly cannot remember being able to loot as Ciri in any other flashback, or having occasion to.

Comment: @SGR You can pick up other things but, as you say, they aren't useful.